# Unable to find saved image

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm very new to Android. I'm working with Xamarin and I have to take a picture with camera and save the picture.

I achieved to take the picture, I have a Bitmap object. Then I save it without error but when I try to find it, there is no file.

There is my code :

```
Bitmap imgBmp = /* image initialized */

//Save image on folder
var folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);               
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "image1.png");
var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
bool isOK = imgBmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 95, stream);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

I have no error when execute, isOK is true but when I search for the image.png I'm unable to find the file.

With debugger I saw that the path is : `/data/user/0/com.myCompagny.MyAppli/files/image1.png` but I can not see that folder.

Can someone help me to find my image1.png ?

Or to change the default folder to something like Pictures\MyApplication\image.png but I don't know how to find default folder for images.

Comment: you can't access this directory with a file manager because it is a system private dir. Only apps can access it, and only their own private dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is there, [but you have no permissions to see it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). App directories are only readable to the owning app's uid. If you try to find your file through the shell, your uid is different.

You should try to use [another folder path](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/12423/#Comment_12423) if you want to save file in a world readable location.

I'm just guessing but maybe `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures` would do.

Comment: Is there a way to save the file as public file ? I'm trying to change the folder but I don't know how to create a folder like "Storage\Pictures\MyApplication"

Comment: Check my edits please. Refer to [SpecialFolder enumeration](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Environment+SpecialFolder/)

Comment: `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures` is an empty String on my application. I've try with `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures` but the result is just "Pictures", not the complete path

Comment: It's ok, I called the method in a bad way. With `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures)` it works.